# Kafka Mirrormaker and record encoding

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I'm trying to replicate a topic from one cluster to another using mirror maker
This topic is configured with an avro schema.

Since I was experimenting with mirror maker I started to do the replication from one topic to another on the same cluster (Kind of dumb but it was to understand how to use mirror maker)
It worked just fine.

Once I was able to do that I use the same configuration to do it from one cluster to another and now the records in the destination topic have broken characters and I do not understand why.

My serialization was configured as String on both sides.
I also tried with ByteArray on both sides when I saw the encoding issue.

Do you have any insight as to why I have this issue ?

Thanks for reading

Comment: I discovered that the serialization properties I was using were useless. Still need to figure it out